# Macro concatenation inside other macro concatenation in c

Tags: c, concatenation

I have the following macros:

```
#define    __IR( x )        ICU.IR[ IR ## x ].BIT.IR
#define     _IR( x )        __IR( x )
#define      IR( x , y )    _IR( _ ## x ## _ ## y )
```

I use it in this way:

```
IR(SCI7, RXI7) = 0;
```

That expands to:

```
ICU.IR[ IR_SCI7_RXI7 ].BIT.IR = 0
```

Instead of use `SCI7` and `RXI7` I'd like to use `sci(channel)` and `rxi(channel)`. So I've tried to create the following macros:

```
#define _sci(x)  SCI ## x
#define  sci(x)  _sci(x)
#define _rxi(x)  RXI ## x
#define  rxi(x)  _rxi(x)

#define channel 7
```

And then:

```
IR(sci(channel), rxi(channel)) = 0;
```

But it didn't work. The compiler returns me:

> Error[Pe017]: expected a "]"

I've been trying to with other manners also but without success.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "But it didn't work", could you be more specific?

Comment: @Eregrith I put the returned error

Comment: Can you compile only the pre-processing step and see what you have? You can do it with `gcc -E` for example.

Comment: I'm using IAR and I don't have gcc. But I will download it and make a test. I will check if IAR have something like this.

Comment: I found the error. The problem is that `SCI7` had already a definition. I think it's better to delete this question. What do you think?

Answer (score 4):

The whole macro is expanded with the literal sub-epressions and the macros in the result expression are expanded after that.

So you could write:

```
#define    __IR(x )      ICU.IR[ IR ## x ].BIT.IR
#define     _IR(x, y)    __IR(_ ## x ## _ ## y)
#define      IR(x, y)    _IR(x, y)

#define _sci(x)  SCI ## x
#define  sci(x)  _sci(x)
#define _rxi(x)  RXI ## x
#define  rxi(x)  _rxi(x)

#define channel 7

IR(sci(channel), rxi(channel)) = 0;
```

(The only thing I've really changed is the definition of `_IR`. On anther note, macro identifiers and symbold beginning with underscores are reserved for the compiler, so you might want to rename your secondary macros.)

Answer (score 2):

You're making the mistake of believing a macro function is like a function call whereas it actually involves text substitution on source code.

In rough terms, the preprocessor will expand `IR(sci(channel), rxi(channel)) = 0` to `_IR( _sci(channel)_rxi(channel)) = 0` and expands that to `ICU.IR[IR_sci(channel)_rxi(channel)].BIT.IR = 0`.   The result of all that is then compiled as C.

That bit between the square brackets is not a valid C expression at all.   The compiler gets confused on that, hence the cryptic error message.

That's the explanation for the problem.   The solution?   You haven't given enough information to help anyone suggest one.

Comment: actually, afaik if you try to use preprocessor directive with another preprocessor directive(`A(B(c))`, where both A and B are macros) causes UB, and compilers are free to treat it whatever way they wont, so chances are on some compilers it would work differently

Comment: Not true Chris.   There is nothing inherently wrong with that sort of usage of macros, as long as the resultant code is valid.